# What's the lowest Type on the Kardashev Scale a civilisation could be for us to take it for God?

Tags: space, aliens, civilization, kardashev-scale, gods

If a Type IV or V civilisation intervened on Earth, we would certainly believe it was nature at work, unless they decided to reveal themselves. Well, then, think they're literally divine entities.

That's for sure.

But what about Type III? Would such a civilization have enough technological advancement for us to take it for God?

I'm ruling out Type II and I civilizations as they are not advanced enough. But is this fair?

So, my question is: what's the lowest Type a civilization must be, to be taken for us as gods?

Comment: Anyone, or anything, could be taken as some kind of God. Even some very convincing guy in the Middle Ages who achieves a cult following.

Comment: I feel like it's a bit subjective to apply the Kardashev Scale here. As @XandarTheZenon said, pretty much anything can be taken as a god. Some folks will never believe that any being is a god; some folks will become believers within five seconds, and others will be in the middle. Everyone will react differently.

Comment: Putting this another way, the answer is subjective.  One person's standard of proof will not be proof to another person.

Comment: I have a lot of trouble picturing what "a civilization in possession of energy on the scale of its own galaxy, " could possibly want with Earth. Unless they were into our equivalent of kicking anthills.

Comment: @T.E.D. They've already tapped every energy source in their own galaxy, *and* they just bought a new toaster, so they want to borrow our mains power to make breakfast.

Answer (score 4):

Many consider Jesus to be God, or at least the son of God.  At that time, that part of civilization was probably working its way up to Kardashev Scale 0, which is 1MW of power produced.  The Egyptians treated their Pharaoh as the incarnation of a God.  They might have actually attained Kardashev 0, given the size of their empire and the amount of engineering power it wielded.

It takes remarkably little power to convince people of Godlike powers, that power merely needs to be well placed enough to be seen as a miracle.